# populate json to html with django template

Tags: python, django, json, django-templates

In order to better debug my api, I would like to create a debug page which shows all details of the response json obj line by line. I think it can be done by code or django template. What is the simplest way to do it?

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET
For example, facebook explorer does list details of the response json obj like this.

```
{
  "id": "xxx", 
  "name": "xxx", 
  "first_name": "xxx", 
  "last_name": "xxx", 
  "link": "xxx", 
  "username": "xxx", 
  "hometown": {
    "id": "xxx", 
    "name": "xxx"
  }, 
  "location": {
    "id": "xxx", 
    "name": "xxx"
  }, 
  "bio": "Drink Coffee in Whitehorse", 

  "work": [
    {
      "employer": {
        "id": "xxx", 
        "name": "xxx"
      }, 
      "location": {
        "id": "xxx", 
        "name": "xxx"
      }, 
      "position": {
        "id": "xxx", 
        "name": "xxx"
      }, 
      "start_date": "2009-01", 
      "end_date": "0000-00"
    }, 
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need to call `json.dumps()` with the `indent` keyword argument equal to the number of spaces to indent the generated JSON by for pretty printing.

For example:

```
json.dumps(spam_and_eggs, indent=4)
```

Answer (score 2):

May I suggest using `<pre></pre>` in your HTML so that your json looks pretty.

```
import json
from django.contrib.admin.views.decorators import staff_member_required
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Scan

    @staff_member_required
    def info(request):
        my_info = Scan.scan()
        return render(request, 'info.html', {'info': json.dumps(my_info, indent=4)})
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre>{{ info|safe }}</pre>
    </body>
</html>
```